$n$-dimensional maximally-symmetric space with metric of an $(n − 1)$-dimensional unit sphere
I only learnt of calculating Christoffel symbols of a 3-dimensional symmetric space metric with spherical metric of 2-dimensional unit sphere, but how do I calculated Christoffel symbols of an $n$-dimensional symmetric space metric with spherical metric of $(n-1)$-dimensional unit sphere.

The same way as usual. Either you can use the brute force method and use the explicit form of the Christoffels in terms of derivatives of the metric, or you can use the more elegant approach of using variational calculus to compute the geodesics of your metric, which directly gives all nonvanishing Christoffels.

my friend put n-1 on the krockneker delta on i and j
